# Not getting MapToStoredProcedure option in OnModelCreating

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on EntityFramework with MVC using Code First approach. I am using an existing DB. When I override the OnModelCreating method, i dont see the option to map my entity to stored procedure.

Any reason why?

Thanks!

Image Attached
[image]

Comment: Add `OnModelCreating` method to question if you still have issue - please elaborate.

Comment: What version of MVC and EF are you using?

Comment: Think you ned to upgrade to EF6 - https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/03/01/whats-new-in-entity-framework-6.aspx

Comment: Hey Thanks. I didn't notice that. The project had EF 4.0. I have upgraded EF and now I am getting that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/code-first-insert-update-delete-stored-procedure-mapping.aspx) for reference:

> The following example automatically creates a stored procedure for
>   Student entity using Fluent API.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().MapToStoredProcedures();
}
```

> The code shown above will create three procedures Student_Insert,
>   Student_Update and Student_Delete. Student_Insert and Student_Update
>   stored procedures have a parameter name which corresponds to the
>   property names. Student_Delete will have a primary key property
>   StudentID parameter.

You can also change the stored procedure and parameter names, as shown below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .MapToStoredProcedures(p => p.Insert(sp => sp.HasName("sp_InsertStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name").Result(rs => rs.Student_ID, "Student_ID"))
    .Update(sp => sp.HasName("sp_UpdateStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.StudentName, "name"))
    .Delete(sp => sp.HasName("sp_DeleteStudent").Parameter(pm => pm.Student_ID, "Id"))
    );
}
```

Comment: I have done the same thing. What my problem is i am not getting the MapToStoredProcedures option in intellisense. I have attached image to the post.

Answer (score 2):

Just update your Entity-framework version 5 to 6 or higher as MapToStoredProcedures method don't support in EF5

Comment: then what is the equivalent method for MapToStoredProcedures() in EF core

Comment: you can use FromSqlRaw

Comment: Then there is no more API for equivalent of MapToStroedProcedures in EF core? right?